# Buttons distributed on top of an image, that stay in the same position no mater the screensize

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making an app in which I am doing the following:

[image: sorry about terrible paint skills]

25 buttons (the red, 5x5) that are equally distributed throughout an image in the background and on the left side 5 buttons (brown) a bit closer to the edge.

I have looked at a few similar questions here, with relative layout, but the problem is that as soon as I adjust for one screen size, it doesn't fit with another any more...

Here is how it looks on my phone screen:

[image: Fits as it should]

On other screensizes:

[image][image]

Here is my code:

(a bunch of code before that, but part about the image):

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/chord_box1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/firstrow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="10" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/empty1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Button"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fretposition1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fretposition2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="2" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fretposition3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="3" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fretposition4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="4" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fretposition5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="5" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/empty2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Button"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_weight="1.1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/empty4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.55"
                    android:text=""
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret10"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/no_press1"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret11"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/finger1"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret12"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/finger1"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret13"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/finger1"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret14"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/finger1"
                    android:text="4"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret15"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/finger1"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/empty3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Button"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/empty5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.55"
                    android:text=""
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret20"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/no_press1"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret21"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/finger1"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret22"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/finger1"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret23"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/finger1"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret24"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/finger1"
                    android:text="4"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/finger1"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/empty6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Button"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/empty7"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.55"
                    android:text=""
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret30"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/no_press1"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret31"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/finger1"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret32"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/finger1"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret33"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/finger1"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret34"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/finger1"
                    android:text="4"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret35"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/finger1"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/empty8"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Button"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/empty9"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.55"
                    android:text=""
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret40"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/no_press1"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret41"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/finger1"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret42"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/finger1"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret43"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/finger1"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret44"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/finger1"
                    android:text="4"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret45"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/finger1"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/empty10"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text=""
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/empty11"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.55"
                    android:text=""
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret50"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/no_press1"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret51"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/finger1"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret52"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/finger1"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret53"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/finger1"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret54"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/finger1"
                    android:text="4"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fret55"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/finger1"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/empty12"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text=""
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/empty13"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text=""
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I've made the first row and tried to make it fit, but I'm not sure how to make it fit on different screens. Is this the right way to do it, or should it maybe be done on the java code instead of the xml?

Comment: Do not try to do this with margins.  Use layout_toLeftOf etc.

Comment: Perhaps GridLayout would work better for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the layout_height of your top-level LinearLayout to "match_parent". Then it will cover the entire screen vertically.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/firstrow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10" >
```

You might need to re-adjust the weights to make it look exactly as it did before.